# angular: anchor link doesn't work on android if its container has ng-click

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-ng-click

I have a PhoneGap app that use Angular.

In the app, I show some content, which, when clicked, should move to another page. However, if links in this content are clicked, they should take the user to their target, and not to the default content click target.

However, I noticed that if the content wrapper has `ng-click`, clicking on the links doesn't take the user to that link. It works perfectly on Chrome on my PC, but not on my Android. This happens even if the `ng-click` attribute is empty, but not if its omitted.

The HTML I used to recreate it is:

```
<div ng-click="">
    some content
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
    other content
</div>
```

As I said, on my PC, this works OK, and clicking the link takes the browser to google.com, but on my Android phone, when I put the above HTML in my PhoneGap app, nothing happens when I click the link. If I remove the `ng-click` attribute from the containing `div`, then the link works OK on the phone.

Any idea why this happens, or, more importantly, how can it be fixed?

Comment: have you tried the name `data-ng-click` insead?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yes, `data-ng-click` makes no difference.

Comment: @MukundKumar Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the clean workaround I found for the problem. In the begining of the `ng-click` code of the wrapper I added the following lines:

```
if($event && $event.target && $event.target.href) {
    $event.target.click();
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return;
}
```

In the `ng-click` attribute, when this code is called, I pass `$event` as an argument.

Also, I'm not sure `$event.preventDefault();` and `$event.stopPropagation();` are really needed. It worked well on my android even without them, but I added them for extra safety.

Comment: @GringoSuave ng-if where? I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have a div with an ng-if/ng-repeat, and a link inside it doesn't work.  If I move the link outside the div, it does work.  But, I need it inside, to only show in certain situations.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help inside the div, no.  If I move it up the chain it works, but then becomes also useless. :/

Comment: @GringoSuave does it work add expected when run in Chrome on a PC?

Comment: Yes, am now investigating angular directive priority.

Comment: I went back to my table that does work, have no idea why there's a difference.